Adding items to a list but getting duplicated values
So I have a class called LedColChangeDate2 that has a constructor that takes a number of parameters. Within this class is a list of it's own classes ( see code if that don't make sense ).
In another class I have a method (addLedToList) that takes some lists from it's own class, makes a new instance of LedColChangeDate2 and adds it to the list in LedColChangeDate2. When I call the method addLedToList the new instance of LedColChangeDate2 is added to the list but the values of the newly added instance are duplicated to every item in the list when I am actually passing in different values each time I add to the list.
I realize this is something to do with the newly added item being a reference variable and with this is mind I tried to change a field of the most recently added item with this:
  int ind = LedColChangeDate2.ledList.length - 1;
  print('index = $ind');
  LedColChangeDate2.ledList[ind].fadeToTime = fadeOnTimes;

But it doesn't make any difference. Any help much appreciated, thanks.
class LedColChangeDate2 {
  static List<LedColChangeDate2> ledList = [];

  LedColChangeDate2({
    required this.ledNo, // int ( not a list)
    required this.codeList, // list of strings
    required this.fadeToTime, // list of strings
    required this.stayOnTime, // list of strings
    required this.colorList, // list colors
  });

  late int ledNo;
  List<String> codeList = [];
  List<String> fadeToTime = [];
  List<String> stayOnTime = [];
  List<Color> colorList = [];

  static bool listCreated = false;

  static void printLedDetails() {
    for (int i = 0; i < ledList.length; i++) {
      print('item no $i');
      print(ledList[i].ledNo);
      print('Colours');
      _printList(ledList[i].colorList);
      print('codes');
      _printList(ledList[i].codeList);
      print('Fade times');
      _printList(ledList[i].fadeToTime);
      print('stay on times');
      _printList(ledList[i].stayOnTime);
    }
  }

  static void _printList(List inputList) {
    for (int i = 0; i < inputList.length; i++) {
      print(' $i  // ${inputList[i]}   ');
    }
  }
}

void addLedToList() {
  print('adding LED to list **************');

  var obj = LedColChangeDate2(
      ledNo: 1,
      codeList: colCodes,
      fadeToTime: fadeOnTimes,
      stayOnTime: stayOnTimes,
      colorList: storedColours);

  LedColChangeDate2.ledList.add(obj);
  int ind = LedColChangeDate2.ledList.length - 1;
  print('index = $ind');
  LedColChangeDate2.ledList[ind].fadeToTime = fadeOnTimes;

  LedColChangeDate2.printLedDetails();
}


I think your mistake here is using static methods and variables, rather than instance methods and variables. Have a read about static variables and methods here: https://www.w3adda.com/dart-tutorial/dart-static-keyword

A [mre] would make it much easier to understand the problem. You could remove all unimportant details, e.g. name your class A, include only one List instance variable, and include a main function so that one can run your code.
